# What's the association between a JavaScript jquery version numbers and a @types/jquery version numbers?

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm working on some legacy code that uses the JavaScript version of `jquery@3.6.4`. I want to include a developer dependency on `@types/jquery@3.6.4`, but it doesn't exist. Actually, when I looked into it, the [jquery js version numbers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery?activeTab=versions) don't seem to relate to most of the [jquery types version numbers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery?activeTab=versions).

How do I find out what version of `@types/jquery` I'm supposed to use with `jquery@3.6.4`?

Comment: jQuery (github.com/jquery/jquery.git) <> jQuery types (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/jquery).  Different projects, different purpose, different author ... and different releases/different versions.  I'm not aware of any guidelines recommending which "types" version to use with any particular version of "jQuery", if that's what you're asking...

Comment: Have you tried looking at npm info @types/jquery? Maybe from this list you can get an idea of ​​the closest one to use.

Comment: @RamonSoarez I've never used that command before, but I don't see a way to use it to answer this question.